# Cannot fill missing values of certain rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am working on imputing NaNs of rows based on certain columns. So my dataframe looks something like this:

| Product | Store Name | January Sales | February Sales | March Sales |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |

For example, `January Sales` would be `NaN` for a combination of `Product` and `Store Name` and am imputing data based on other months averages. Also, other attributes, `February Sales` might also have NaNs in the same row.

The code that I used was:

```
indexes = df.index[df['January Sales'].isna()].to_list()
fillCols = df.iloc[:, 3:]
df.loc[indexes, 'January Sales'].fillna(fillCols.mean(axis=0), inplace=True)
```

But the above code doesn't seem to be working, the code won't impute data, however, when broken down different pieces do work, how to solve this problem?

Comment: Are you trying to replace your nan with the mean for january or for january, february and march?

Comment: Please include a small subset of your data as a copyable piece of code that can be used for testing as well as your expected output for the provided data. See [MRE - Minimal, Reproducible, Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples).